# How do I set Text size by emulator setting text size in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, debugging, android-emulator

I wanna change text size not by android:textSize but change in setting emulator front size

Comment: See settings on the emulator -Screen - Font size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the setTextSize function on the TextView reference.